# Converting Degree, Minute, Second (DMS) to Decimal in PHP is not fully correct

Tags: php, gps, decimal, latitude-longitude, dms

I've seen several solutions for this problem, but all of them are incorrect.
I have this GPS data from a photo:

```
Latitude:
47/1
5/1
33927/1000

Longitude:
17/1
54/1
44513/1000
```

I've used this formula to get the decimal coordinates: `Degrees = D + ((S/60)+M)/60`

The results are: `47.084722222222 , 17.915` 
But according to Google's converter it should be `47.092758 , 17.912365`

This small difference means a half city.

In PHP:

```
$exif = exif_read_data('temporary/' . $_FILES['photo']['name']);
        //LONGITUDE
        $degLong = explode('/', $exif['GPSLongitude'][0]);
        $minLong = explode('/', $exif['GPSLongitude'][1]);
        $secLong = explode('/', $exif['GPSLongitude'][2]);

        $longitude = ($degLong[0]/$degLong[1]) + (($minLong[0]/$minLong[1])/60) + (($minLong[0]/$minLong[1])/60)/60 ; 

        //LATITUDE
        $degLat = explode('/', $exif['GPSLatitude'][0]);
        $minLat = explode('/', $exif['GPSLatitude'][1]);
        $secLat = explode('/', $exif['GPSLatitude'][2]);

        $latitude = ($degLat[0]/$degLat[1]) + (($minLat[0]/$minLat[1])/60) + (($minLat[0]/$minLat[1])/60)/60 ;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You seem to be missing the actual code that is giving you the incorrect results.

Comment: When you're calculating latitude and longitude you're using minutes twice and seconds not at all.